# How do you migrate Redshift Database to another Redshift Cluster

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want to transfer 1 or more Redshift Database from a Redshift cluster to another cluster in the same region.

The existing target cluster has the same schema.

```
Redshift Cluster Source
|
|_ DB_1
|_ DB_2
|_ DB_3
```

```
Redshift Cluster Target
|
|_ DB_A
|_ DB_B
|_ DB_C
```

After transfer...

```
Redshift Cluster Source
|
|_ DB_1
```

```
Redshift Cluster Target
|
|_ DB_A
|_ DB_B
|_ DB_C
|_ DB_2
|_ DB_3
```

So far I've only read of UNLOAD & COPY command, but that only works for tables, and I have a lot of tables for each database. Is there a more efficient way to transfer database? Or an existing tool?

Comment: what sort of size (how many GB) are you looking at moving?

Comment: I have about 5GB per database, and I plan on migrate one DB at a time.

Comment: I am using Data Virtuality which provides access to two clusters. It helps me to move data from one to another using INSERT INTO...SELECT FROM queries. The AWS Schema Conversion Tool can help you take DDL of the source tables and create them on the target cluster

Answer (score 0):

A python script can be used to connect to both the clusters, and then you could loop over all the tables to copy from Cluster A to Cluster B.

> **psycopg2** is a good library to make Redshift connections via Python. Ref [here](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/).

Here's a sample code that could be helpful for your usecase:

```
import psycopg2

# Define source and target cluster credentials
src_host = 'source_cluster_hostname'
src_dbname = 'source_database_name'
src_port = '5439'
src_user = 'source_username'
src_password = 'source_password'

tgt_host = 'target_cluster_hostname'
tgt_dbname = 'target_database_name'
tgt_port = '5439'
tgt_user = 'target_username'
tgt_password = 'target_password'

# Connect to source and target clusters
src_conn = psycopg2.connect(host=src_host, port=src_port, dbname=src_dbname, user=src_user, password=src_password)
tgt_conn = psycopg2.connect(host=tgt_host, port=tgt_port, dbname=tgt_dbname, user=tgt_user, password=tgt_password)

# Get a list of all tables in the source database
cur = src_conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname='public'")
tables = [row[0] for row in cur.fetchall()]

# Copy each table to the target database
for table in tables:
    print(f"Copying {table}...")
    cur.execute(f"COPY {table} TO STDOUT")
    with tgt_conn.cursor() as tgt_cur:
        tgt_cur.copy_expert(f"COPY {table} FROM STDIN", cur)
    tgt_conn.commit()

# Close connections
src_conn.close()
tgt_conn.close()
```

*Note*: If your table sizes are huge, you might want to consider optimizing using  UNLOAD command instead of COPY to unload the data from the source cluster into S3, and then use the COPY command to load the data from S3 into the target cluster. Use psycopg2.extras.execute_batch() method to execute the UNLOAD and COPY commands in batches for better performance.